# Why is the if block being evaluated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, autofill

I am working on a rails project where I am auto-filling a form's from email field through JQuery if the user is signed in. I am using devise for authentication.

```
var user_signed_in = "<%= current_user.blank? %>";

if (!user_signed_in){
  var user_signed_in = "<%= current_user.email %>";
  $('input#inquiry_from_email').val(user_signed_in);
}
```

As per the code the contents inside the if block should not be evaluated but I am getting undefined method 'email' for nil class error in case of guest user.

**If the  current_user.blank? is evaluated to false and I am checking it in the if block before hand, I am not understanding why the statements inside the if is ever being evaluated.**

Comment: *"If the current_user.blank? is evaluated to false"* - Huh? Your *JS* if condition will be false if `"<%= current_user.blank? %>"` evaluates to anything other than an empty string. All of the server-side code is evaluated first (on the server, obviously), then later the JS is evaluated by the browser.

Comment: user_signed_in? Use devise helper to check if user is logged in

Comment: Bug 1: The `#blank?` method will return a Ruby `true` or `false` so your `user_signed_in` JavaScript variable will hold the string `'true'` or the string `'false'`. Bug 2: All your Ruby will be executed before your JavaScript so `current_user.email` will be evaluated (in Ruby) before the value of `user_signed_in` (in JavaScript) is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will be executed because you have ruby code within JavaScript code. When page is served then it will execute the JavaScript code. You need to put whole of your code within if block

```
<% if current_user %>  
    var user_signed_in = "<%= current_user.email %>";
    $('input#inquiry_from_email').val(user_signed_in);  
<% end %>
```